# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I searched a lot of questions , but none of the answers helped me ! I connected an activity with a navigation drawer to a fragment ... but I start from this mistake ! Thanks for your help!

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
```

xml class

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:background="@color/colorAccent">
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

hedline fragment

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {

String[] Headlines = {
        "Article One",
        "Article Two",
        "Article 3",
        "Article 4",
        "Article 5",
        "Article 6",
};

SearchView search_view;



OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

String[] menutitles;
TypedArray menuIcons;

CustomAdapter adapter;
private List<RowItem> rowItems;

// The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
    int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, null, false);











}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
        RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
                i, -1));

        rowItems.add(items);
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);




}




@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
    // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Notify the parent activity of selected item
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

}

main activity of fragment`

```
public class MainActivity_list extends FragmentActivity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

    // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }
}

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

    // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

    } else {
        // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

}

article fragment.java

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
int mCurrentPosition = -1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
    // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
    // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
    // below that sets the article text.
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        // Set article based on argument passed in
        updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
    } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
        // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
        updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
    }
}

public void updateArticleView(int position) {



}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
    outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
}
```

}

mainactivity.java (of navgation drawer)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

String[] lista = {
        "Article One",
        "Article Two",
        "Article 3",
        "Article 4",
        "Article 5",
        "Article 6",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);






    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.btnMyMenu) {

                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    };




    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
               drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
    });



   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);
    // Convert ArrayList to array

    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_menu,R.id.menu_text, lista));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Intent activity0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, pagina1.class);
                    startActivity(activity0);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Intent activity1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, pagina1.class);
                    startActivity(activity1);
                    break;


            }

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }

        ;
    });

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    int menuToUse = R.menu.my_right_side_menu;

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(menuToUse, menu);

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    return true;
}
```

}

there is also a rowitem.java, customadapeter.java

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.chiari.nicola.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.chiari.nicola.myapplication.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Error say: Change the `DrawerLayout` width to some definite value like `240dp` instead of `match_parent`

See the source Code:

```
 if (widthMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY || heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            if (isInEditMode()) {
                // Don't crash the layout editor. Consume all of the space if specified
                // or pick a magic number from thin air otherwise.
                // TODO Better communication with tools of this bogus state.
                // It will crash on a real device.
                if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                    widthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                } else if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
                    widthMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                    widthSize = 300;
                }
                if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                    heightMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                }
                else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
                    heightMode = MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
                    heightSize = 300;
                }
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: did u change the width or height?

Comment: if i change the width gives me the same error ... if I change the height works but is not the same for all devices

Comment: u have set the height or width dynamically by calculating height of device at runtime

Comment: I did not understand what should I change

Comment: change listview height to match_parent and removeandroid:layout_gravity="end" from drawerlayout and retry

Comment: try putting your app_bar and framelayout in a linear or relativelayout with width height match_parent

Comment: sorry... but the same error!! there is not a solution!

Comment: post your appbar_main layout

Comment: i find the solution with custom drawer layout!

Comment: Add width to your navigation view not to DrawerLayout

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, during investigation I discovered that it was because `HorizontalScrollVIew` was in my view hierarchy, try to play with that